# How to find span class value present under a particular td

Tags: jquery

On click of a Radio button , i am trying to chnage the value of a Button text .

But i am facing problem with the jquery selector in this case

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="customer_details_table" aria-describedby="sample_1_info" style="display: table;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Contact No.</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="odd gradeX">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" class="bradio" id="20" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td width="20%">kiran</td>
            <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
            <td width="20%">7654321987</td>
            <td width="20%">venkatrajkiran@yahoo.com</td>
            <td width="10%" align="center"> <span class="label label-success">Active</span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" class="bradio" id="28" name="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td width="20%">kiran</td>
            <td width="25%">XXXXXXX</td>
            <td width="20%">9701429843</td>
            <td width="20%">s@g.com</td>
            <td width="10%" align="center"><span class="label label-inverse">DeActive</span> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" id="deactivebtn" class="btn blue">Deactive</button>

$(document).on('click', '.bradio', function (event) {
    var classname = $(this).find('span').attr('class');
    if (classname == 'label label-success') {
        $('#deactivebtn').text('Deativate');
    } else if (classname == 'label label-inverse') {
        $('#deactivebtn').text('Deativate');
    }
});
```

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kz2j2jjy/7/

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
var classname = $(this).find('span').attr('class');
```

for this:

```
var classname = $(this).closest('tr').find('span').attr('class');
```

Basically first go to mutual parent node and then find your **span**.

Comment: Yep. To expand, `this` was your `input.bradio`. Obviously, you weren't going to find a span inside of it.